# Geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ when $x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and so is convergent for $|x|<1$.

While working on a trigonometry problem I came across the case of what happens when $x=0$. Clearly the sum is $1$ with the convention $0^0=1$ (this convention is discussed in several threads here on MathSE).

However Wolfram Alpha says about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0^n$:

> (sum does not exist due to singularity at one or more evaluation points)
>
> By the geometric series test, the series diverges.

My assumption is that Wolfram Alpha doesn't know what to do with $0^0$. There have also been several threads on MathSE about various ways in which Wolfram Alpha fails or uses certain unstated conventions.

Is there something else I am missing?

Ultimately I am interested in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\arctan(\sin(\theta)))^n$ (which is not hard to analyze), and had a problem evaluating it at $\theta=0$ on Wolfram Alpha. I'm including this problem on an upcoming test, so I wan't to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything. I suppose I could just start at $n=1$ to avoid any possible issue.

---

**EDIT:** The answer was provided by @Masacroso in the first comment below. See [indeterminate forms on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0). Wolfram Alpha does indeed consider $0^0$ to be undefined.

Comment: wolframalpha doesnt use the convention $0^0:=1$, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0). Also $(\arctan(\sin 0))^0=0^0$ so this is the same problem for wolframalpha.

Comment: With the convention $0^0=1$ the series is indeed $1$ as you say. This is just a difference in convention with wolfram alpha.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming my suspicions. @Masacroso, your link is the solution to my question. Thanks.

Comment: The nice thing about Mathematica is that it allows you to override some of its conventions. One example is $\mathtt{Unprotect[Power]; 0^0=1}$.

Comment: I just discovered that Octave (Matlab) gives $0^0=1$ as well. Good to be aware of!